# How can make custom shape with picture (inside the shape)

Tags: android, android-shape

I'm new in android programming and I try design this shape:

check [this link](https://github.com/Kirollos-Mallak/shape/blob/main/WhatsApp%20Image%202021-08-11%20at%202.48.14%20PM.jpeg) to see the shape that I want to design it

how can make this shape, and how to put picture in the shape like Alexandria?

can any one help me?   ***plz answer with all details to understand the code***

thanks

Answer (score 1):

add dependency in build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.mask.PorterShapeImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:siShape="@drawable/shape" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
    }
}
```

drawable resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFC107" />
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
        android:topRightRadius="70dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="70dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dip" />
</shape>
```

output

[image: output]

Comment: and how insert picture in this shape ?

Comment: I have edited the answer please check @Kirollos Mallak

Comment: thanks for your answer...... @Tanveer Hasan 
I'm using Kotlin ( Is that will mack different ?  )
there is something else I'm using card view and recyclerView, so can I use the shape and insert the picture ( in XML, not Activity like you did  )

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ShapeableImageView` for this, which is provided in the `material` components package. If you are already using material theme in your project, then you are good to go, otherwise, add `material` dependency.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

And inherit, you `AppTheme` from `MaterialComponents`, in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
     ...
     ...
</style>
```

Add a new style to `style.xml` for creating the rounded corner of the image.

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.RoundedCorner" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">75dp</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">75dp</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomLeft">rounded</item>
</style>
```

Change your `ImageView` to a `ShapeableImageView` in layout, and add above `ShapeAppearnaceOverlay` style to it, using `app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.RoundedCorner"`

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pots"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.RoundedCorner"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toEncrypt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/decrypted"
        android:id="@+id/encrypted" />
```

**Note** - Use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`, so you don't get a clipping effet on either side of the image.

**Result** -

[image: Result]